# Background Picture With Website In Middle

Tags: html, css

So I want my website to have the content in the middle of the page with a static background picture while I go down the page, like [this page](http://www.gldesert.com/). How can I get that to work? I have looked at everything I possibly can, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/). Have you viewed their source to see how they did it?

Comment: I looked at the source, the CSS stylesheet, etc.

Comment: You have 5 answers which do what you want.. Consider selecting the right answer, otherwise comment on them if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

They more than likely used CSS to achieve this effect. The first thing we need to do is to set the background image.

```
body {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
}
```

Next we need to set the background attachment using the `background-attachment` property.

```
body {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This will achieve the effect you want, a background image that scrolls with the page. Note that unless the image is big enough, the background color will show through.

---

**Edit:** You can set the background to not repeat by setting the `background-repeat` property.

```
body {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

---

**Edit:** You can set the background's position via the `background-position` property. In order to center it we would do.

```
body {
  background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: How do I add a no-repeat element to this? I see a bunch of my image

Comment: But then it isn't in the center... =/

Comment: @KeybordPiano459 Updated answer and fixed mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but one more question - can I get the image to go to the top center?

Comment: @KeybordPiano459 Just change `background-position` to `top center`.

Comment: @KeybordPiano459 If somebody's answer helped you you should upvote them and accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

They're using a library called jScrollPane.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

The relevant markup is below, you should search for it in the inspector.  When you do, you'll see that the 'top' property is being changed as you scroll.

```
<div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; width: 569px; top: -271px; "><div id="tab1" class="tab_content" style="display: block; ">
                            <div class="inner">
                                    <div class="review_block">
                                        <figure><img src="http://www.examiner.com/images/blog/EXID43556/images/vote_check_image.jpg" width="190" height="190" alt=""></figure>
                                      <div class="img-wrap"><strong>Vote, Vote, Vote!!</strong>
                                        <p>Vote fast!</p>
                                        <strong>The votes on MinecraftServers.net have reset! Get us over a hundred or two right off the bat at 12AM, and we will be the best!  For the next week, we are raising the reward amount too 20 diamonds per vote!  Happy voting, Thanks!</strong></div>
                                    </div>
                                  <div class="review_block">
                                        <figure><img src="images/diamond.png" width="190" height="190" alt=""></figure>
                                        <div class="img-wrap">  
                                            <strong>New Website!</strong>
                                            <p>It's awesome!</p>
                                        <strong>We love the new look of things, it's cleaner and up-to-date!</strong></div>
                                  </div>
                                    <div class="review_block">
                                        <figure><img src="images/page1_img1.jpg" width="190" height="190" alt=""></figure>
                                      <div class="img-wrap"><strong>New Domain Name!</strong>
                                        <p>www.gld.bz</p>
                                        <strong>New Domain Name! Easier to remember, type, and it actually fits on signs and in chat better! Just a shortcut for www.gldesert.com</strong></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="review_block">
                                      <figure><img src="images/arrow.png" alt=""></figure>
                                      <div class="img-wrap"><strong>Upgraded Server!</strong>
                                        <p>So much faster, and 0 lag!</p>
                                        We went to the furthest extent possible, We rented out Google.... Ok, maybe not Google, but it's close enough. We have 512GB SSD, 32GB of RAM, 8 Core CPU @ 3.8GHz a core. Infact, here is the servers temporary theme song!<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf?audioUrl=http://gldesert.com/music/better.mp3" height="27" width="320">                                 </div>
                                    </div>
                              <div class="review_block">
                                      <figure><object width="425" height="350"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/lp-62YcdpxU&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=1&amp;volume=" 25"=""><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/lp-62YcdpxU&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=1&amp;volume=" 25"&akkiwfullscreen="1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="190&quot;" height="144"></object></figure>
                                        <div class="img-wrap">  
                                            <strong>Video Contest is over!</strong>
                                            <p>And the winner is.... Silver Vapour!</p>
                                           Congrats SilverVapour! You have received a free Captain Rank! Awesome job with the video!
                                        </div>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                            </div><div id="tab3" class="tab_content" style="display: none; ">
                              <div class="inner"></div>
                          </div></div>
```

Comment: I've heard of this before, but I'm not completely sure how it works. First of all, what exactly is it?

Comment: Also, which one is it? There's like a million demos on that page

Comment: What it's doing is setting the position of the container to relative, and then the content inside is absolutely positioned.  As you scroll through, the script detects the mouse scrolling and adjusts the 'top' position property.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I was looking at the page you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use "position:fixed" for your background image.  Then give it a low z-index to put it behind everything.  Just put everything else in like normal.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
The css for your background image should look like:

```
#backgroundImage{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Everything else will be left the same.

Comment: You might want to add that you apply this to an image and that html and body need to have a `min-height` of 100 percent.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `background-attachment: fixed` for the background image.

To keep the content in the middle please add following CSS

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    width: 1009px;
}
```

container is the id of the element having main content

Comment: Wrong attribute, `background-position: fixed` is not valid and won't work.

Answer (score 0):

the html

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<h2>Hi how are you?
content goes here
</h2>
</div>
</body​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​>`
```

The css

```
body {
background-image: url(/path/image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position:top center;
}
#container {
background: white;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 20px;
width: 400px;  /* change to suit need*/
}​
```

Example of how it appears: http://jsfiddle.net/rgZgY/